# How to make a totals page in php with data from two tables in MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL database for which I am trying to develop a php interface for a stock tracking database. The database has the following tables  and fields (simplified). Goods will be received from suppliers and then be issued out to personnel. The database intends to track the goods
The tables and fields are 
tblparts (partID, PartName, Category, Decsription)
tblissues (partID, IssueID, DateIssued, Quantity, IssuedTo)
tblreceipts (partID, ReceiptID, DateReceived, ReceivedFrom, VoucherNo, Quantity)
I have need of help and I am a self taught new comer to MYSQL and PHP having moved from a self taught MS Access. Infact this database is working in Access but now it is needed online hence my switching to php
First I need a table the will summarize the receipts and issues and will be grouped by partID. The code that I have used is this it is however giving false calculations I don’t know what I have done wrong
Summary.php (the working assumption is that all goods will be received first so there can not be an issuing out without a receiving first, but there can be a receiving without an issuing out or there might also be a part without any received goods or issued goods.  )

```
    <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
    <title>View Transactions</title>
<h1>Transactions</h1>

</head>
<body>

<?php

    // connect to the database
    include('connect.php');


 // query db

 $PartID = $_GET['PartID'];
   // get results from database
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT tblparts.PartName, tblparts.PartID, tblreceiving.ReceivingID, tblreceiving.DateReceived, tblreceiving.VoucherNo, SUM(tblreceiving.Quantity), tblreceiving.ReceivedFrom, tblissues.IssueID, SUM(tblissues.Quantity), tblissues.IssueDate, tblissues.IssuedTo
FROM tblparts

LEFT JOIN tblreceiving
ON tblparts.PartID=tblreceiving.PartID
LEFT JOIN tblissues
ON tblparts.PartID=tblissues.PartID

WHERE tblparts.PartID=$PartID
GROUP BY tblparts.PartID
ORDER BY tblreceiving.TransDate") 
           or die(mysql_error());  


    echo "<p><b>View All</b> </a></p>";

    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
    echo "<tr> <th>Part Name</th> <th>Amount Received</th></tr>";

    // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

            // echo out the contents of each row into a table
            echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . $row['PartName'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['SUM(tblreceiving.Receipts)'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['SUM(tblissues.QtyIssued)'] . '</td>';
 echo "</table>";
?>

<p><a href="home.php">Home</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Second is the code to enter received goods as well issued goods? Currently I have the following code which is supposed to insert into receipts table but giving an error I don’t know where I have got it wrong
The html form for inserting data

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="insert_receipts.php" method="post">
Transaction Date: <input type="text" name="DateReceived" />
Voucher Number: <input type="text" name="VoucherNo" />
Received From: <input type="text" name="ReceivedFrom" />
Quantity: <input type="text" name="Quantity" />
Unit: <input type="text" name="Unit" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The insert_receipts.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("stockcontrol", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO tblreceiving (Transaction Date, Voucher Number, Received From, Quantity)
VALUES
('$_POST[DateReceived]','$_POST[VoucherNo]','$_POST[ReceivedFrom]','$_POST[Quantity]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";
```

mysql_close($con)

I would wish if the insert_receipts.php would also have a running total if that’s not asking too much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment, not an answer, but trying to format this kind of comment is too hard for me...

```
SELECT p.PartName
     , p.PartID
     , r.ReceivingID  <--
     , r.DateReceived <-- THESE WILL ALL BE ARBITRARY. IS THAT WHAT YOU WANT?
     , r.VoucherNo    <-- 
     , SUM(r.Quantity)
     , r.ReceivedFrom <-- 
     , i.IssueID      <-- 
     , SUM(i.Quantity)
     , i.IssueDate    <-- 
     , i.IssuedTo     <-- 
  FROM tblparts p
  LEFT 
  JOIN tblreceiving r
    ON r.PartID = p.PartID
  LEFT 
  JOIN tblissues i
    ON i.PartID = p.PartID 
 WHERE p.PartID = $PartID
 GROUP 
    BY p.PartID
 ORDER 
    BY r.TransDate
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. I placed it where i have the select query and instead of processing it the browser is returning the select statement

Comment: Tried what? This isn't an answer. It's merely a comment that utilised the formatting options of an 'answer' for clarity.